# How do I forward my old Outlook.com emails to a different email?

Tags: outlook.com, outlook-on-the-web

How do I forward my old Outlook.com emails to a different email or to a file at least so that I can access the information in the future? (My Outlook account is being closed by my employer.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a desktop email client such as Thunderbird/Outlook. The client will fetch your emails for offline use and then you will be able to save your data from the program.

An alternative for this is to have a Google mail account which will allow you to import your old emails directly into your new Gmail account's inbox.

[Source](http://lifehacker.com/5990556/how-can-i-save-all-my-work-emails-for-a-personal-backup).

Comment: Thanks. Will the google/gmail option work if I am accessing the email account remotely via outlook webmail? I am not physically at the employer.

Comment: it should work since you will be fetching your emails directly from Outlook's servers.  
also you may have to check if your employer will let you download your data before proceeding to your account's deletion.